# What units are used in GeoDjango's OSMGeoAdmin slippy map?

Tags: django, openlayers, geodjango

I'm trying to understand what are these two numbers that don't look like decimal degrees:

```
3406661.86743, 6516779.16222
```

Update:

I guess it's part of WKT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSMGeoAdmin's maps are projected in [web mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator).  The coordinates are meters.

Answer (score 1):

According to [GeoDjango documentaion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#osmgeoadmin-intro), it uses the spherical mercator projection. And you need to [add that projection to `spatial_ref_sys` table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/install/#addgoogleprojection) if you are running GDAL 1.6 or below.